# GCP - Can we know who run most of the query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there any way to find out Bigquery details like:

No of Users (per day) (with their name)
No of Queries (per User, per day)
Average Data Usage (per Query)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible.

Here is a [BigQuery audit logs overview](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs)

You might need to establish a near real time export of the log into a BigQuery for further analysis, like in the example here: [Defining a BigQuery log sink using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#defining_a_bigquery_log_sink_using_gcloud)

When (meta) data appears in BigQuery tables, you may use standard SQL queries to get reports you would like, or expose them into some dashboard.

Comment: It's the best way! Use bigQuery to query BigQuery logs! In addition, you can also rank the user per number of request (useless) and by ByteBilled (very interesting)!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following query to verify Queries process over BigQuery, by which user with start and end date.

```
SELECT
   job_id,
   start_time,
   user_email,
   total_bytes_processed,
   query
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
 AND job_type = "QUERY"
 AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
```